# Jmeter throughput controller actions run per iteration

Tags: jmeter

I have the following scenario.

```
HTTP Cookie Manager - clear cookies after each iteration
Login http action -> 30% 
Show profile (the user must be logged in) -> 20%
Purchase (the user must be logged in) -> 50%
```

The problem is, in presence of throughput controller there is no guarantee that per iteration the user will be logged in before any other action that requires the user to be logged in, so after any iteration the cookies will be cleared which means the session will be invalidated, there is a probability the the action will fail since no user logged in.

Taking into account the clear the cookies is a need.

If there is a way like per each iteration the login will be triggered once and the other actions will be repeated to target the throughput controller.
Is there any idea that is suitable for my scenario using jmeter?

Comment: put login above/outside of throughput controller

Comment: That will make login to run each time and won't run 30% of the actions.

Comment: so you want to login every time ("per each iteration the login will be triggered once"), but you want to login in 30% of iterations ("login to run each time and won't run 30% of the actions")? I don't get it. You can have one or the other, not both

Comment: Consider a solution of trigger login action first time and then repeating the other actions to target the percentages.

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario does not make a lot of sense as given the user needs to be logged in in order to perform `Show profile` and/or  `Purchase` tasks you should perform login for 100% of users before viewing the profile or making the purchase. So I would recommend moving your `Login http action` outside the Throughput Controller like:

- Login http action
- Show profile

  - Throughput Controller
- Purchase

  - Throughput Controller

Another option will be using [Switch Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller), this way you will get confidence that each child test element will be executed at least once. Check out [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) article for more details.